# Why is no work done by a force on an object if the object moves in such a way that the point of application of the force remains fixed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

The following statement is given in one of my physics textbooks:

> No work is done by a force on an object if the object moves in such a way that the point of application of the force remains fixed.

But I could not think of any examples where object moves but the point of application of force remains fixed and the net work done is zero.

Can someone explain why the quoted statement is true with some examples?

Comment: Related: [Does the displacement in the definition of work correspond to the displacement of the object or the point of application of the force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121893/238167) & [What if the point of application of force doesn't move but the force itself moves, does it count as work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331469/238167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the force exerted by a pivot (for example, at the top of the chain on a swing).

Clearly the pivot point does not move, hence $W=F.d=F(0)=0$ even though the force exerted by the pivot is nonzero ( or else the swing would fall to the ground).

Answer (score 0):

The Statement says that point of application does not move but you are saying that pivot does not move . pivot is not the point of application it is the point which applies the force.